# Scroll down on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to scroll down about 50px when the page is loaded. This is what I'm using:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("html,body").scrollTop(55);
});
```

I've also tried:

```
scrollTo(0,55)
```

This works fine in Firefox and IE, however in Chrome, Safari and Opera it scrolls down to the proper position and then jumps back up to the top(or the last scroll position).

I've also tried using an element id to scroll down, but the browser still overwrites it. I tried like this:

```
htttp://website.com#element
```

Comment: Try to put your code inside the DOM ready function instead `$(function(){ $("html,body").scrollTop(55); });`

Comment: Just tried it, still gets overwritten by the browser.

Comment: Do you have a hash in your url also ?

Comment: @f00bar The `$(function(){})` construct in jQuery is just an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){})`, so it's the same thing. Both wait for the DOM ready event (among other complicated checks to deal with cross-browser inconsistencies).

Comment: @kenbyes still there is code executed behind the scene that may be the reason why some browser do not behave the same way `:/` Just supposing so

Comment: The only way I could get this to work was using a timeout, setting it to just 1ms.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that you are using $(window).load and some browsers are having problem as things havnt fully rendered yet. Try swapping to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html,body").scrollTop(55);
});
```

Seems to work fine in all browsers here http://jsfiddle.net/7jwRk/1/

Info

**$(document).ready**

executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready

**$(window).load**

executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

Comment: Your jsfiddle does also use `$(window).load()`

Comment: This works, but not when I put in my page, I think this works because js fiddle runs the code in an iframe.

Comment: If you try doing something like this it might show you when and if something is highjacking your scrollTop $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000, function(){alert("got here"));

Comment: @user2204158 this will also work if you select 'no wrap - in body' in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Just tried again(not in jsfiddle, but my site), it still doesn't work. The only solution that seems to work is with a timeout.

Comment: I decided on the solution above but with a slight timeout(50ms or so).  A thing to consider is that on some browsers(or at least Chrome), the scroll position gets saved, so scrolling down will work only the first time the user opens the page.(it get's cleared when the browser is closed)

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var divLoc = $('#123').offset();
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divLoc.top}, "slow");
 });
 </script>
```

Add id="123" to any `<div>` it will automatically scroll it down when page loads.

Here's an another script if the previous one wont work !

```
  <script>
 window.setInterval(function() {
 var elem = document.getElementById('fixed');
 elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;  }, 3000);
 </script>
```

Add id="fixed" to any `<div>` it will automatically scroll it down when page loads.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scrollIntoView() function. This is supported accross most browsers (even IE6).

```
document.getElementById('header').scrollIntoView()
```

Answer (score 1):

After messing with `scrollIntoView()`, and observing it scroll correctly at page paint time, then snap to the top for no reason, I went with this:

`http://website.com/#target`

and

`<a name="target">`

Then the browser understands exactly what I need and does it. But I can only do this because we control the URI, so it naturally also won't work in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just fire this at the end of your body:

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("html,body").scrollTop(55);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using 2 monitors, be sure that when you open the window of your browser with the page for which the script is implemented, you don't move that window to the other monitor, with a different screen resolution. Shortly: don't cross the windows of the browser to a different monitor, just open a new window of the browser for each monitor/ screen resolution.

Comment: This answer is not related to the question itself. Even if working with two monitors can change some behavior, that's not related with how to scroll on page load.